# jQuery Message Box

Tags: jquery

I have a list page with multiple users listed (a favorites list for the logged in users). There is a message button which opens up an overlay. The user can then send a message across using the message box in the overlay. The jQuery code is:

```
$('#message').click(function(){
  var str = $(this).attr('name');
  var n=str.split("####");

  $('#user_new').val(n[0]);
  $('#msgto_username').html(n[1]);
  $('#bodybg').show();
  $('.confirmBox').fadeIn();
  return false;
});
```

However, only the first entry in the list manages to display the message box, for other entries the page just refreshes. The message button HTML is:

```
<a href="" id="message" class="btn" name="<?php echo $user['userid'] .'####'. ucfirst($user['name']) ." ". ucfirst($user['first_name']." ".$user['last_name']); ?>" title="<?php echo 'Send message to ' . ucfirst($user['name']) ." ". ucfirst($user['first_name']." ".$user['last_name']); ?>">Message</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code, use the .live(), .click() do not check for new html entry's. [More info](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('#message').live("click", function(){
    var str = $(this).attr('name');
    var n=str.split("####");

    $('#user_new').val(n[0]);
    $('#msgto_username').html(n[1]);
    $('#bodybg').show();
    $('.confirmBox').fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

I hope that's what you where looking for?

Comment: Not wotking, in fact this part of the code does not even matter because the dialogue box is not opening . I inserted an alert and even the alert is not triggered . So it's not even calling the function for the other entries .